# Wi-fi AP disappears after connecting to mobile hotspot

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, tethering

My Windows laptop is connected to my home wi-fi AP. The wi-fi router has both 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands, and I can see both stations, plus a list of those in the neighborhood when I click the network icon in the System Notification area.

I then set up my Android phone as a hot-spot. I connect my lap-top to the hot-spot. Everything works out fine.

After working for about 30 minutes with no trouble, I then shut down the hot-spot on the phone. My laptop is now unable to see the two (2.4GHz and 5GHz) APs on my home router. Other APs in the neighborhood can still be seen.

No amount of disabling/enabling the wifi adapter on my laptop will make it see my home APs again until I reboot.

This problem is reproducible every time I go through the same sequence. What could be happening?